# Filter data along with pagination Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following code that filter professors by department

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened">
<div class="depts">
  <app-departments (filterByDeptEvent)="filterProfByDept($event)" [depts]="departments"></app-departments>
</div>
```

And this is the html that displays the professors, through the currentItemsToShow property, in the same file:

```
 <div class="content" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">
  <div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.sm="33%" *ngFor="let prof of currentItemsToShow">
    <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{prof["fullName"]}}</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          Department: {{prof["department"]}}
        </p>
        <p>
          Overall rating: {{getProfOverallRating(prof['ratings'])}}
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/home-page/prof-detail/{{prof['id']}}">See details</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
<mat-paginator (page)="onPageChange($event)" [length]="100" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

In the ts file, this fetches data from api and then paginates:

```
professors = [];
currentItemsToShow = [];
defaultRecords: any = 5;
departments = [];
dept: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
this._professorService.getProfessors().subscribe((data) => {
  this.professors = data;
  this.professors.forEach((prof) => {
    if (this.departments.indexOf(prof['department']) === -1) {
      this.departments.push(prof['department']);
    }
  });
  this.departments.push('All departments');
  this.currentItemsToShow = this.professors.slice(0, this.defaultRecords);
});

}
```

This code gets the department from the component app-departments and then assign it to "dept" property:

```
filterProfByDept(dept: string) {
    this.dept = dept;
};
```

This code supports pagination:

```
   onPageChange($event) {
    this.currentItemsToShow = this.professors.slice($event.pageIndex * $event.pageSize, $event.pageIndex * $event.pageSize + $event.pageSize);
  }
```

Right now this works fine to display the professors and paginate the data, however, I would like to integrate the filter by the department with this code, how would I do that?

In the past, when I didn't have to do the pagination thing then in the *ngFor part I just create a function that takes in the department and filters the professors and call `*ngFor="let prof of function(department)"` and it works fine.

I would really appreciate any help. I'm sorry this is a bit long but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just do the same way by modifying the function that filter by departments a little:

```
 processedProf(dept: string) {
    if (this.profName == '') {
      if (dept === "All departments" || !dept) {
        return this.currentItemsToShow;
      }
      return this.currentItemsToShow.filter(prof => prof['department'] === dept);
    } else {
      if (dept !== "All departments" && dept) {
        return this.currentItemsToShow.filter(prof => prof['department'] === dept).filter(prof => prof['fullName'].toLowerCase().includes(this.profName));
      }
      return this.currentItemsToShow.filter(prof => prof['fullName'].toLowerCase().includes(this.profName));
    } 
  }
```

And call `*ngFor="let prof of processedProf(dept)"` on the display and it worked...